# What is the maximum size of a bucket on Google Cloud Storage? When should I use multiple buckets for one web app?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm working on a web app where users can sign up to a service and then upload things to a Google Cloud Storage bucket.

As I would like the app to scale to thousands of users I was thinking that I probably need to dynamically create new buckets at some point. However, having consulted the google documentation I didn't find the maximum size a bucket can reach and I don't even know whether it is necessary to create new buckets to "scale out".

Any advice on these issues would be appreciated.

Kind regards,
w34

Comment: it's not necessary to create "new" buckets. If there was a maximum size I'm sure it would have been mentioned! Let google worry about scaling buckets, it's after all why you pay them.

Answer (score 19):

There's no size limit for a bucket, the only limit you have is 5TB maximum size per uploaded file.

You can use multiple buckets not mainly for scalability but for access rights management and to structure your data